# Is there a way to getPixel(x,y) without a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener, android-bitmap, getpixel

[image: Pie]

Hi everyone. So I asked a question about custom shaped buttons yesterday and it got downvoted. I have done more research since and I think I'm ready to ask something more specific.

Basically, I need to turn each portion of this pie into a button. The pie is an SVG path drawn with `VectorDrawable` and is a Drawable resource in an `ImageView`. The reason I'm not using a bitmap is because I want this pie to be scalable.

I searched high and low for a solution. I considered mask the pie with a transparent pie drawn with `PathShape` and somehow turning that into a button, but that didn't work out because Drawables aren't clickable. Someone suggested Android Radial Menu, but I thought, I'm just trying to implement 6 buttons. There has to be a simpler way.

Then I realized that I had decidedly drawn my pie with such vivid colors and considered using `OnTouchListener` to call the 6 different things I want to do based on what color the user touched. I thought it was a brilliant idea. But I have hit a roadblock, because `getPixel()` has to be used on a bitmap.

So I was wondering if there is still a way to get the color of the pixel touched in an `ImageView` that doesn't actually have a bitmap.

Any other suggestions on how to solve my problem would also be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `...  in an ImageView that doesn't actually have a bitmap` Everything you display in an ImageView is previously transformed into a Bitmap. So... what are you asking?

Comment: Is it really? I thought that the idea of the ImageView and a bitmap, is that an ImageView is like a picture frame and the bitmap is a raster resource that is drawn onto the picture frame when called. But my SVG is a vector, not a raster. To get the color of a pixel with OnTouchListener, there has to be a variable along the lines of `int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);` but I don't have a bitmap. Or are you saying that I do? If I touched the red pie piece, how can I get `OnTouch` to return #FF0000?

Comment: No, the ImageView is a `canvas` and it always contains a raster image (a.k.a. `Bitmap`). The SVG is first converted to a Bitmap, and then it's **painted** onto the ImageView. You always have a Bitmap in an ImageView. Or nothing. So, you have to retrieve the Bitmap from your ImageView. Then, from that Bitmap, retrieve the color at the specified coordinated. I'd go for a ready-made library. Maybe modify that one, if it doesn't satisfy me 100%.

Comment: I see. Okay, that makes sense now. Thanks @BobMalooga, for coaching me yesterday and today. Thank you so much. I'm definitely learning.